# JScrollPane Confusion

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

So, I'm attempting to add in a JScrollPane to a JTextArea so that I can scroll down, but no matter what I do, the pane does not show up. Am I in violation of some Swing stuff, or just a fail? Also, this is for a school project so I really need a definitive answer as quickly as possible. Thanks!
Here's the code for the class implementing the JScrollPane:

```
package BLANK.historicalcontext;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import BLANK.historicalcontext.gui.ConsoleJTextArea;
import BLANK.historicalcontext.keys.ConsoleKeyListener;
import BLANK.historicalcontext.story.Backstory;
import BLANK.historicalcontext.story.Story;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public static ConsoleJTextArea console = new ConsoleJTextArea();
    public static JTextField inputField = new JTextField();

    public static Story currentStory;

    public static Font font = new Font("Avenir-Light", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    private void addComponentsToPane() {
        setLayout(null);

        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

        inputField.addKeyListener(new ConsoleKeyListener());

        console.setEditable(false);

        console.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 250));
        console.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
        console.setFont(font);

        inputField.setFont(font);

        Insets insets = getContentPane().getInsets();

        JScrollPane consoleScrollPane = new JScrollPane(console);
        consoleScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20 + insets.left, 800 - 20 + insets.top));

        getContentPane().add(inputField);
        getContentPane().add(consoleScrollPane);

        console.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 10 + insets.top, 800 - 20, 600 - 65);
        inputField.setBounds(7 + insets.left, (600 - 70) + 20 + insets.top, 800 - 14, 20);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        Window frame = new Window("Historical Context Project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addComponentsToPane();

        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        frame.setSize(800 + insets.left + insets.right, 600 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        inputField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public Window(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            console.printToConsole("UnsupportedLookAndFeelException caught: \n" + ex.getStackTrace().toString() + "\n");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            console.printToConsole("IllegalAccessException caught: \n" + ex.getStackTrace().toString() + "\n");
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            console.printToConsole("InstantiationException caught: \n" + ex.getStackTrace().toString() + "\n");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            console.printToConsole("ClassNotFoundException caught: \n" + ex.getStackTrace().toString() + "\n");
        }

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

        console.append("Hello! This is a text-based game about the creation of the creation of Java.");
        console.printToConsole("Your name is Patrick Naughton.");
        console.printToConsole("Here is a bit of backstory:");

        currentStory = new Backstory();

        if(currentStory != null) {
            currentStory.executeStory();
        }
    }

    public static void failGame() {
        console.printToConsole("You failed the game. This application will close once you click the \"Enter\"/\"Return\" key.");
    }

}
```

I imagine you'll also want to see the class that the console is based off of:

```
package nate.historicalcontext.gui;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ConsoleJTextArea extends JTextArea {

    public void printToConsole(String message) {
        this.append("\n"+ message);
    }

}
```

Also, please don't refer me to another question because no two questions are completely alike and my situation may differ from the author of that question's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Over use of `static`. `static` is not a means for cross object communication.  Provide methods which allow you to access the properties of the object that other objects need.  Try and be protective of your data/fields
2. `null` layouts. You don't control many aspects of the rendering process which can change the requirements of individual components and affect their relationship to other components.
3. Adding the `console` to the `contentPane` AFTER it was previously assigned to the `JScrollPane`. A component can only reside within a single container, when you add it to another container, it is removed from the current container first

Have a closer look at [How to use scrollpanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

```
JScrollPane consoleScrollPane = new JScrollPane(console);
//...
// Add the scroll pane...
getContentPane().add(consoleScrollPane);
// Add the console, which WAS on the scrollpane to the content pane
getContentPane().add(console);
```

Your use of `null` layouts is not helping you...

[image: Layout]

```
  private void addComponentsToPane() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    setContentPane(panel);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

//  inputField.addKeyListener(new ConsoleKeyListener());

    console.setEditable(false);

    JScrollPane consoleScrollPane = new JScrollPane(console);

    console.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 250));
    console.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
    console.setFont(font);

    inputField.setFont(font);

    getContentPane().add(inputField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(consoleScrollPane);
//  getContentPane().add(console);

    Insets insets1 = getContentPane().getInsets();
//  console.setBounds(10 + insets1.left, 10 + insets1.top, 800 - 20, 600 - 65);
//  inputField.setBounds(7 + insets1.left, (600 - 70) + 20 + insets1.top, 800 - 14, 20);
  }
```

Comment: Do I still add the `scrollPane` to the `contentPane` or no?

Comment: First, you do `getContentPane().add(consoleScrollPane);` which is good, then you do `getContentPane().add(console);` which is bad

Comment: So I should get rid of `getContentPane().add(console);`? Because then the console doesn't show up on the screen.

Comment: Again, in that case console doesn't show up on the screen

Comment: The I would suggest it's an issue with your `null` layouts

Comment: It can't be. I used the insets in setting the `consoleScrollPane`'s size. It should be fine. (Edited OP)

Comment: See update, works find when I don't use null layouts

Comment: When I add `System.out.println(consoleScrollPane.getBounds());` to your code, it prints `java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]`.  Remember also, `console` is under the constraints of the scroll pane and the scroll pane has it's own layout manager

Comment: Why do you use `console.setBackground(Color.RED);`?

Comment: *"I used the insets in setting the consoleScrollPane's size"* - Actually, you didn't, but non-the-less, I'd avoid `null` layouts, On my system, the caret in your text field couldn't blink properly because the field was to short...

Comment: @TheAustralianBirdEatingLouse `Why do you use console.setBackground(Color.RED);`, sorry, that was me debugging. *"Also, I still don't see the scroll bar there."* - Firstly, that's how mac renderers it, secondly, the default policy will only show the scroll bars `WHEN_NEEDED`

Comment: @TheAustralianBirdEatingLouse Glad we got ourselves through that :P

Comment: Slightly irrelevant question, what program do you use to get that rendering of the window?

Comment: MacOS has an inbuilt screen shoot tool [command]+[shift]+[4], then pressing [space] it allows you to capture the window. On windows I use [GreenShot](http://getgreenshot.org/) as it allows you to easily capture the active window

Comment: I also have a completely unrelated question I'm going to ask in a separate post, so if you could help me on that too that would be great. Thanks in advance!